# How to update deep objects in a nest react

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I need help making a handler that will update the nested object state.

Here is the sample code

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    permanentAddress: {
        street: '',
        city: ''
    },
    currentAddress: {
        street: '',
        city: ''
    }
});
const handler = (e) => {
    setState({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

Then I import a custom textfield

```
export const CustomTextField = (props) => {
    const { handler, ...rest } = props
    return (
        <TextField {...rest} onChange={handler} />
    )
}
```

Now I know this will only create a new key named `street` with the value instead of updating the one already in the state. I have also thought of just adding a prop that will indicate whether it is nested, something like

```
<CustomTextField cat='permanentAddress' name='street' handler={handler} />
```

Then I will change the handler to something like this, passing along `cat` in the parameter

```
const handler = (cat, e) => {
    if (cat) {
        const category = {...state[cat]}
        category[e.target.name] = e.target.value
        setState({...state, [cat]: category})
    } else {
        //non-nested update here
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you move addresses to different useState?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149659/8437974